# Jquery textbox returns no value in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

Is there a work around to get the value of the textbox? Let's say I set the textbox datepicker to `09-14-2014` then after clicking button it returns no value.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[id$=txtDate1]").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                buttonImage: 'Images/calendar.png'
            });
        });
    </script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate1" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Comment: Could it be that you have different time formats on the server and on the client?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `read only` values is posted back to the server.

You can remove server side `ReadOnly` and use this on page load.

```
txtDate1.Attributes.Add("readonly","readonly");
```

**Or** you can use `Request.Form` collection to get the values.

```
string date1 = Request.Form[txtDate1.UniqueID];
```

Comment: Sure they are. Elements with `disabled` do not get posted.

Comment: Should I remove it or just make it false?

Comment: @AndreiV but .net does not use it.

Comment: @NatsuDragneel you need to remove form `.aspx` and use `attribute` on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **ReadOnly="true"** from

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate1" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

And in code behind add **txtDate1.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");**

By doing this you can retrieve read-only textbox's value in the code behind.